# Ubuntu's equivalent for MacOS any app Help search

Tags: search, helpfile

I switched from MacOS to Ubuntu this weekend .

I'm used to a functionality I had with MacOS I want for all my apps in Ubuntu.

For any app in MacOS, you can search through the different commands within the app thanks to their names, as follow:

[image]

Here for instance, I searched for Close a tab in Chrome. Furthermore, Chrome gives me what is the corresponding shortcut for what I search, if it exists, and where it is in the different panes.

How can I add it to all my Ubuntu apps?

For instance, in LibreOffice Writer, I wanted to search for rounding corners of an image, but I couldn't find it thanks to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app developer makes that functionality available, you will find it with <kbd>F1</kbd>.